# Is it not possible to create an app as local business (Facebook page)?

Tags: facebook

I’m trying to create an app at developers.facebook.com when I’m logged in as local business user (page). Under *Apps* there isn’t any **Create new app** button. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. As stated by a Facebook employee

> 'Business' or advertising accounts can't manage apps - if you were
>   able to create one as a business account this is a bug or loophole and
>   shouldn't have been possible - only real verified user accounts should
>   be able to create and manage apps.
>
> If you need to share ownership of the app between multiple people you
>   can do so either via making a Facebook Group an admin and adding the
>   other admin users to that group, or by adding the users directly via
>   the
>   [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#props)
>   or the 'Roles' tab of the App settings: ![Role management popup with
>   'Create Group' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3mvX.png)
>
> You can also specify a business account which will manage the ads for
>   an app in the app settings - on the Advanced tab - but this is
>   effectively the only supported connection between apps and business
>   accounts - [image: screenshot here]

<sub>Source: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account</sub>

Comment: In this case the local business(facebook page) wants to add facebook comments(facebook app) to their website and get an overview of the comments on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ when logged in as local business account.

Comment: Adjustments:
In this case the local business(facebook page) wants to add facebook comments(facebook app) to their website to get an overview of the comments on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ when logged in as a local business account. 


Only possible solution?:
The local business(company) then has to use a personal verified account to create apps and therefore cant't log in as a local business account to see the comments?


Or what is best practice in this case?


Help would be very much appreciated :-)

Comment: @SuneBruunOlsen correct the local business would need to use a personal verified account

Comment: Can I create a fictive verfied personal account for this, as we do not want the comments to follow a single emplyee, or what is best practise regarding this? I am guessing that fb might delete fictive accounts right?

Isn't there an official facebook guide for this somewhere?

Comment: @SuneBruunOlsen Creating a fictional account will get it deleted and may get you banned if they can trace any associations to it. The best practice is to create an agreement between the developers and the company on ownership and responsibility of code. The only way you can create an application is by using a personal account from then onwards you can use Application Roles and Groups to handle additional developers and admins of the company http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/ http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/531/